# Fine-tuning BERT sentence transformer model

Tags: bert-language-model, sentence-transformers, fine-tuning

I am using a pre-trained BERT sentence transformer model, as described here https://www.sbert.net/docs/training/overview.html , to get embeddings for sentences.

I want to fine-tune these pre-trained embeddings, and I am following the instructions in the tutorial i have linked above. According to the tutorial, you fine-tune the pre-trained model by feeding it sentence pairs and a label score that indicates the similarity score between two sentences in a pair. I understand this fine-tuning happens using the architecture shown in the image below:

[image]

Each sentence in a pair is encoded first using the BERT model, and then the "pooling" layer aggregates (usually by taking the average) the word embeddings produced by Bert layer to produce a single embedding for each sentence. The cosine similarity of the two sentence embeddings is computed in the final step and compared against the label score.

My question here is - which parameters are being optimized when fine-tuning the model using the given architecture? Is it fine-tuning only the parameters of the *last layer* in BERT model? This is not clear to me by looking at the code example shown in the tutorial for fine-tuning the model.

Comment: All layers that your input has passed will be fine-tuned unless you have frozen them.

Comment: Thank you @cronoik Do you know how i can specify in the train function which  layers to freeze? For instance, I want to freeze all layers except the last one.

Comment: Somewhere in your code you are initializing the optimizer like `AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=2e-5)`. Just use a variable instead of `model.parameters()` that doesn't contain the last layer.

Answer (score 0):

That actually depend on your requirement.
If you have a lot of computational resources and you want to get a perfect sentence representation then you should finetune all the layers.(Which was done in the original sentence bert model)

But if you are a student and want to create an almost good sentence representation then you can train only the non-bert layers.